# How to implement this animation on a widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to implement this animation on a custom made tile.
So how can we implement this slide animation to highlight a widget.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Kkml.gif)

So give your suggestion to make it possible

Comment: I think you can try with ShaderMask

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh I also tried ShaderMask but how to add the horizontal line below it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've another best and short solution. Firstly Add these packages in pubspec.yml-
flutter_animate: ^4.2.0+1
shimmer: ^3.0.0

```
Container(
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  border: Border(
                    bottom: BorderSide(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      width: 2,),
                  ),
                ),
                child: CustomSettingListTile(
                  prefixIcon: Icons.currency_rupee,
                  labelText: "Subscription Plus",
                  trailingWidget: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                    size: 20,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  onTap: () {
                    // Get.to(() => const FeedbackScreen());
                  },
                ),
              )
            .animate(
                onPlay:(controller) => controller.repeat(),
              )
              .shimmer(
                angle: 0,
                duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                color: Colors.orange.shade600
              )
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 1):

Use this package **animations: ^2.0.8**

Comment: Could you explain why? Show a code example that solves this question. Code snippets works as well.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use this package "marquee 2.2.3".

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution of this by writing custom code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class LinearWidgetHighlighter extends StatefulWidget {
   const LinearWidgetHighlighter({
     Key? key,
     required this.childWidget,
     required this.gradientColors
   }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget childWidget;
  final List<Color> gradientColors;

  @override
  State<LinearWidgetHighlighter> createState() => _LinearHighlighterState();
}

class _LinearHighlighterState extends State<LinearWidgetHighlighter> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {

  late final AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController.unbounded(vsync: this)
      ..repeat(min: -1,max: 1.5,period: Duration(milliseconds: 2500));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: _animationController,
      builder: (_,child) {
        return ShaderMask(
          shaderCallback: (rect) {
            return LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: Alignment.centerRight,
                transform: _SlideGradientTransform(parent: _animationController.value),
                colors: widget.gradientColors
            ).createShader(rect);
          },
          child: child,
        );
      },
      child: widget.childWidget,
    );
  }
}
class _SlideGradientTransform extends GradientTransform{
  final double parent;

  const _SlideGradientTransform({required this.parent});
  @override
  Matrix4? transform(Rect bounds, {TextDirection? textDirection}) {
    return Matrix4.translationValues(bounds.width*parent, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

We can use it like...

```
Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              LinearWidgetHighlighter(
                  childWidget: CustomSettingListTile(
                    prefixIcon: Icons.currency_rupee,
                    labelText: "Subscription Plus",
                    trailingWidget: const Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
                      size: 20,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      // Get.to(() => const FeedbackScreen());
                    },
                  ),
                gradientColors: [
                  Colors.white,
                  Colors.orange.shade600,
                  Colors.white,
                ],
              ),
              LinearWidgetHighlighter(
                childWidget: const Divider(),
                gradientColors: [
                  Colors.transparent,
                  Colors.orange.shade50,
                  Colors.orange.shade300,
                  Colors.orange.shade600,
                  Colors.orange.shade300,
                  Colors.orange.shade50,
                  Colors.transparent,
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
```